# What causes the web socket connection loss?

Tags: websocket

I use web socket for a server client connection of ocpp server. Ithappens so many times that Web Socket connection is closed without giving any reason in log.

So what i'm trying to find out is: in this cases how could i analyse the reason behind it? How is that effected? I just at the first point want to get a better understanding of how i could debug it

here below is, what i see in the log

```
self = <websockets.server.WebSocketServerProtocol object at 0x7163b930>

    async def ensure_open(self) -> None:
        """
        Check that the WebSocket connection is open.
    
        Raise :exc:`~websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed` if it isn't.
    
        """
        # Handle cases from most common to least common for performance.
        if self.state is State.OPEN:
            # If self.transfer_data_task exited without a closing handshake,
            # self.close_connection_task may be closing the connection, going
            # straight from OPEN to CLOSED.
            if self.transfer_data_task.done():
                await asyncio.shield(self.close_connection_task)
                raise self.connection_closed_exc()
            else:
                return
    
        if self.state is State.CLOSED:
>           raise self.connection_closed_exc()
E           websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason

../../.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/envs/evse-test-stand/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py:803: ConnectionClosedError
```

Comment: Could you share your code to have a better understanding of the problem?

Comment: I'm testing a functionality of ocpp server. Seing the original code think doesn't help a lot, but i send what i see in log.